# Unable to save PowerPoint presentation. Some of your fonts cannot be saved with the presentation. Reason: NotTrueType

Tags: powerpoint

Here's the image of the error menu itself:

[image: Image of error menu]

I tried to replace the font with another one but I got this error: "You selected a single-byte font to replace a double-byte font. Please select a double-byte font."

[image: Second error]

The weird thing is I can't find this font being used anywhere. Please help. I used a template from slidesmania.com and I'm creating this presentation with a team. One of my teammates might be using Ubuntu. I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If there's so much as a single space or other character formatted in that font, you'll have this problem. There's an add-in called SlideWise (https://neuxpower.com/slidewise-powerpoint-add-in) that will work around this problem. They have a 30 day free trial ... might be worth giving it a go.  Fifty bucks to buy.  Very reputable company, well known in the industry.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I checked every slide, every bit of text and couldn't find this font anywhere. I was able to finally save it though. I don't know what I did to fix it but it's currently saving even with this menu so I'm fine for now. Thank you for the info though!